# Get error when trying to access my link

Tags: hyperlink, web-hosting

I've just started to learn HTML and I did my first website. Inside on the "Home" button I put a normal link who go to `www.google.com`, in my local file in the computer is working OK but after I update on the web host and I click it I get an error `The requested URL /idevelop.org/http//:www.google.com` was not found on this server.

This is my web site http://idevelope.tk/ try even you, and tell me what I am doing wrong. I know is not the best one but is my first one after 3 days of learning, so don't be bad.

Thank you very much for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "home" button click to visit any URL,The hyperlink tag should have URL http://www.google.com instead of http//:www.google.com